# OSX cronjob doesn't have permission to touch existing files in Downloads?

Tags: macos, cron, crontab

I recently updated from OSX 13.2 to 13.5.2 and all my cronjobs are failing now.

I'm trying to run rsync in a cronjob but it keeps failing, and I ultimately narrowed that down to my cron jobs not having permissions to edit *existing* files in `~/Downloads` for some reason?  (Works fine in `~`).  `cron` has full disk access permissions in system settings.

I made my crontab:

```
* * * * * echo "Hello World" >> "/Users/me/Downloads/foo.txt"
* * * * * echo "Hello World " >> "/Users/me/Downloads/bar.txt"
* * * * * whoami >> /Users/me/Downloads/whoami.txt
```

`foo.txt` was directly created by me by just `touch foo.txt`, the other two were created by the cron tasks.  The `foo.txt` task fails, the other two work every minute.

`ls -l` shows:

```
-rw-r--r--@  1 me  staff    52 Sep 18 10:12 bar.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 me  staff     0 Sep 18 10:06 foo.txt
-rw-r--r--@  1 me  staff    15 Sep 18 10:12 whoami.txt
```

and given that the only thing apparently different is the `@`, I found [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106642/what-does-the-at-symbol-mean-on-osx-ls).

`ls -l@` yields nothing apparently useful:

```
-rw-r--r--@  1 me  staff   143 Sep 18 10:19 bar.txt
        com.apple.macl    72
-rw-r--r--   1 me  staff     0 Sep 18 10:19 foo.txt
-rw-r--r--@  1 me  staff    50 Sep 18 10:19 whoami.txt
        com.apple.macl    72
```

The mail from crontab:

```
From me@computer  Mon Sep 18 10:20:01 2023
Return-Path: <me@computer>
X-Original-To: me
Delivered-To: me@computer
Received: by computer (Postfix, from userid 501)
        id A3DCC30D0D9; Mon, 18 Sep 2023 10:20:01 +0200 (CEST)
From: me@computer (Cron Daemon)
To: me@computer
Subject: Cron <me@computer> echo "Hello World" >> "/Users/me/Downloads/foo.txt"
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=me>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=me>
Message-Id: <20230918082001.A3DCC30D0D9@computer>
Date: Mon, 18 Sep 2023 10:20:01 +0200 (CEST)

/bin/sh: /Users/me/Downloads/foo.txt: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Not my forte, but see if https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378553/crontab-operation-not-permitted helps at all. Also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/461289/task-scheduled-as-a-cronjob-not-executing

Comment: @Tetsujin - Unfortunately not.  I already gave `cron` full disk access, there seems to be something else that's changed between OSX 13.2 and 13.5.2 (so basically some time this year)

Comment: Ahh, OK. Above my paygrade, I'm afraid. Wish you luck :)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I just ended up moving my rsync job to a folder outside of `~/Downloads` and it works again.  Still very curious as to what's breaking here though